# timer schedule method exceeds the time

Tags: java, android

I use the timer schedule method to send location information to the db every 5 min.

Here is the code:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
{
    this.timer.schedule(new Send(), new Date(), TEN_SECONDS*6*5); //ten_seconds = 10000
}

class Send extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        String address = LocationService.this.address;
        new SendLocation(LocationService.this.id,address); // a thread that sends the info to the db
        LocationService.this.gpsLocation = null;
        LocationService.this.networkLocation = null;
    }
}
```

But how come that my db has locations with 7/6 minute diffrence?
The sendLocation checks if the location that i'm going to send to the db is the same as the last one, if true ignore the location else send it.

Which means that the diffrence between each location in my db should be in jump of 5 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee your `TimerTasks` will be executed exactly when you request. From the [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) docs --

> Each timer has one thread on which tasks are executed sequentially.
>   When this thread is busy running a task, runnable tasks may be subject
>   to delays.

and

> This class does not offer guarantees about the real-time nature of
>   task scheduling

Granted, two minutes is a long time, so there might be delays elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Watch [**this**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) link about `Timer` `schedule` Method. It clearly says that :

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution,
>   beginning at the specified time. Subsequent executions take place at
>   approximately regular intervals, separated by the specified period.
>
> **In fixed-delay execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the
>   actual execution time of the previous execution. If an execution is
>   delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background
>   activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well.** In the long
>   run, the frequency of execution will generally be slightly lower than
>   the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock
>   underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).

In your code It might be possible that the `run` method of `Send` is taking more than 5 minutes to complete its task because of some heavy task to be performed by `SendLocation` `Thread`. So Your db has locations with 7/6 minute difference.